# Reactjs `openAlertAbsent` is not a function

Tags: reactjs

After opening the popup, when i click the icon close i've receive an error saying `openAlertAbsent` is not a function`

```
const [openAlertAbsent, setOpenAlertAbsent] = useState({
        open: false,
        success: false,
      });

 .....
setOpenAlertAbsent({
  open: true,
  success: true,
})
 .....

  const handleAbsent = () =>{
    if (openAlertAbsent.success) {
      openAlertAbsent({
        open: false,
        success: false,
      });
    }
  }


  ....

   <AlertIgnoreStudent
        open={openAlertAbsent.open}
        handleClose={handleAbsent}
        success={openAlertAbsent.success}
   />
```

Comment: please upload your codesandbox and point out where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [openAlertAbsent, setOpenAlertAbsent] = useState({
        open: false,
        success: false,
      });

 .....
setOpenAlertAbsent({
  open: true,
  success: true,
})
 .....

  const handleAbsent = () =>{
    if (openAlertAbsent.success) {
      openAlertAbsent({  // here is a problem, maybe setOpenAlertAbsent?
        open: false,
        success: false,
      });
    }
  }


  ....

   <AlertIgnoreStudent
        open={openAlertAbsent.open}
        handleClose={handleAbsent}
        success={openAlertAbsent.success}
   />
```